# Allow certain users to by-pass the gated check-in on TFS

Tags: tfs

I want to enable the gated check-in trigger for my `TFS` Build but also want to have a way to specify users who can commit their code directly without waiting to `TFS` to verify their code changes.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you edit the "Security" of the build definition:

[image: Build definition]

There is a permission you can control called "Override check-in validation by build" (or similar, I don't have TFS 2012 to hand, I'm using VSTS for the screen shots).

[image: definition permissions]

Grant certain people this permission and they can bypass the validation.

When they check-in code they will get the usual Gated Build prompt, but under "Show Options" there is a checkbox to bypass the validation:

[image: Bypass gated build]

By default Project Administrators and upwards have this permission.

Answer (score 1):

For TFS 2015 Right click on the build definition, select security.Then change **Override check-in validation by build** to Allow

[image]

Comment: I think this is the same as what @DaveShaw suggested. Thanks!

Comment: How to do the same in Azure DevOps, when using Visual Studio 2019.  I don't see the "Override..." option inside security.